# Problems launching java programs in Windows Command Line after Java Update 281

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, java, jdk, jre

After updating [Java 8](https://java.com/sv/download/java8_update.jsp) (update 281) yesterday (2021-02-15) I could no longer use the [Single-File Launch](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) in the Windows Command Line. Prior to this I had no problems using this feature but now I get the following error;

Error: could not find or load main class *filename*.java

What did this update change or mess up? I'm very fond of the Single-File Launch feature and I would be very sad to never be able to run java files like this again. What can I do to fix this, any suggestions?

Details: I'm using the standard Windows 10 command line (cmd.exe).
I have not updated the PATH variables because I don't know what to change to be honest, it worked before. Here's what I currently have in there that is relevant to Java;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin

Comment: What the exact command line you are using? Did you update the Java related environment variables when you updated? Please [edit] the question and do not reply in the comments.

Comment: According to your link, single file launch was delivered in Java 11 so if you have replaced the default Java to version 8 then launch from .java file will stop working.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have Oracle javapath (which is probably picking Java8) before Java13 binaries which would stop the single file/compile launch working as `java xyz.java`.

See @DrMoishe Pippik answer for helpful info editing the path, you could try swapping the order of these directories so that Java13 is first - if that directory exists:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

But note: this may lead to a secondary issue because other apps may fail if they depend on the Java8 installation over the Java13. Confirm which default is used in CMD.EXE with:

```
java -version
```

If you want multiple JDK and have need for CMD.EXE which prefers specific JDK version you can add shortcuts to desktop with following commands:

```
%COMSPEC% /V /K C:\somepathtoyourbin\java8.cmd

%COMSPEC% /V /K C:\somepathtoyourbin\java13.cmd
```

... and add files to set the preferred JAVAHOME in `java8.cmd` or  `java13.cmd`. Example `java13.cmd` might be:

```
@echo off
set "JAVAHOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1"
set "PATH=%JAVAHOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the environment variable(s) for the [path to *java.exe* need to be updated](https://www.baeldung.com/find-java-home). First, check where *java.exe* and/or *javaw.exe* are in your PC file system. Then, open a CMD prompt, and type

```
echo %java_home%
```

or

```
where java
```

If that path is incorrect because of the update, the easiest way [to correct it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) in Windows is with the Environment Variable editor.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `envi` and select `Edit the system environment variables` [You must be an Administrator to do this.].
- Select any variable with a java path that is incorrect and edit it.
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `envi` and select `Edit environment variables for your account`.
- Select any variable with a java path that is incorrect and edit it.

You may need to reboot for the changes to take effect.