# Setting up different console entry point for different environments

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I frequently work in lots of different multi-tool environments depending on what task I'm doing.

1. C++ native windows dev requiring LC, NMake etc.
2. Node.js env with python3
3. C++ Mingw dev requiring GCC, make etc.
4. Embedded C using different version of GCC
5. LaTeX

I want to have different console entry points and starting a different terminal has different PATH configurations so as to not include folders I don't need.

Why? I've been stung enough times thinking something is wrong with my code or that the command line tool is not working before realising the wrong tool is being used due to mutiple entries in the path.

I feel like this is fairly easy with a .bat script for each setup but I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to setup simple CMD files with the settings per environment and create a desktop shortcut per console of each type. A simple example of this for handling different PATH setup for multiple installations of Java is found at the end of this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1626562/problems-launching-java-programs-in-windows-command-line-after-java-update-281/1626787#1626787).

A more flexible version of above is to have one `env.cmd` and pass in a variable to select the config so that you can re-use common paths for other tools all consoles need. For example if you had 2 desktop shortcuts as follows:

```
%COMSPEC% /V /K set MYENV=python&& C:\pathtoyour\env.cmd

%COMSPEC% /V /K set MYENV=cpp&& C:\pathtoyour\env.cmd

%COMSPEC% /V /K set MYENV=jdk19&& C:\pathtoyour\env.cmd
```

Note: no space before && or MYENV will end with a space. An example `env.cmd` would be able to fill in bit specific for config "python" / "cpp" and have common bits too:

```
@echo off
if "%MYENV%" == "python" (
   set "PYTHONHOME=PathtoPython"
   set "PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PATH%"
)
if "%MYENV%" == "cpp" (
   set "PATH=PathtoC++Home;%PATH%"
)
if "%MYENV%" == "jdk19" (
   set "JAVA_HOME=PathtoJDK"
   set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%;%PATH%"
)
:: Items here for all envs
```

Comment: Got there in the end. Thank you.
I also added: 
`
if "%PLATFORM%" == "" (
   set /p PLATFORM="Enter desired console platform (python, web, cpp):"
)
`