# Add launch commands to Command Prompt in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-11, windows-terminal

In a similar way to `.bashrc` on WSL2, I want to add custom commands to run when I open the Command Prompt in Windows Terminal, like `winfetch` for example. Is there any way to configure the Command Prompt profile so that it executes custom commands at startup?

Comment: Possible cross-stack duplicate: [How to run a command on command prompt startup in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows).  If you are using PowerShell instead of CMD, see [about_Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: We don't do cross-stack duplicates. You should rather put up an answer.

Comment: This is also [answered here](https://superuser.com/questions/1628632/setting-up-different-console-entry-point-for-different-environments/1628654). You just assign different script or env variable in the command line of each Windows Terminal profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by providing an autorun script for cmd.exe.
This is set via registry.

Open registry with `regedit`

navigate to:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

A REG_SZ registry variable `Autorun` should exist with value set to 0.
If registry variable not exits, create variable `Autorun`.

Set variable to your script, i.e. `"%YOUR_PATH_TO_FILE%\my_startup_script.bat"`

Example:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun="%USERPROFILE%\my_startup_script.bat"
```

It is also possible to use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`.

Further reading:
[Hidden gotcha: The command processor's AutoRun setting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433)

Comment: It works, magical. Note to self and others, put `call`  before every line if the `.bat` file has multiple lines.

Comment: @OtávioAugustoSilva - The `CALL` in a `.bat` file is only necessary if you are trying to invoke one `.bat` file from another - you don't, for example, need `CALL NOTEPAD.EXE FOO.TXT` or `CALL DIR *.TXT`. It's also used for labelled subroutines within a single `.bat` file; see [SS64 on `CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin didn't know that, thanks for the info!